# How Can i replace the newlines with colon within the range of lines in SED

Tags: sed, awk

I would like to search through  range of lines in a file  between the lines that begins with start and ends with End and replace the newlines with colon. I need this to be done in SED or AWK.

Example file:

```
start
a
b
c
End
Start
a
b
c
End
Start
x
y
z
End
```

Expected Output:

```
a:b:c
a:b:c
x:y:z
```

Comment: sed is an excellent too for simple substitutions on a single line. Period. Do not even consider sed for anything else, that's what awk is for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this short awk one-liner should work:

```
 awk -v RS='Start|End' -v OFS=":" '$1=$1' file
```

with your data:

```
kent$  cat f
Start
a
b
c
End
Start
a
b
c
End
Start
x
y
z
End

kent$  awk -v RS='Start|End' -v OFS=":" '$1=$1' f
a:b:c
a:b:c
x:y:z
```

Comment: I think it should be mention that this need `gnu awk` due to multiple characters in `RS`. But its a nice solution :)

Comment: the '$1=$1' force re-computation of $0, getting rid of leading/trailing spaces, and changing the ones in the "middle" to be replaced by the OFS ':'. From posix awk: "Setting any other field causes the re-evaluation of $0." (the RS=... line changes record separator from the usual "newline" to either "Start" or "End" (so your file could contain only "Start ... a b c ... Start" and still work. Note that "$1=$1" also force it to only match lines containing something

Answer (score 1):

Let's give a try with `awk`.

```
$ awk '/start/ || /Start/ {next} /End/ {print line; line=""; next} {if (line) {line=line":"} line=line$0}' file
a:b:c
a:b:c
x:y:z
```

#### Explanation

- `/start/ || /Start/ {next}` on lines containing "start" or "Start", skip.
- `/End/ {print line; line=""; next}` on lines containing `End`, print the `line` variable that contains the loaded information. Delete the value of the var and go to the next line.
- `{if (line) {line=line":"} line=line$0}` on the rest of the lines, keep loading data in the `line` variable. The `if` condition is to avoid having a trailing `:`.

The `/start/ || /Start/ {next}` can be reduced to both of these ([thanks Jotne](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20519360/how-can-i-replace-the-newlines-with-colon-within-the-range-of-lines-in-sed#comment30677083_20519446)):

```
/start|Start/ {next}

/(s|S)tart/ {next}
```

Comment: `/start/ || /Start/` can be shorten to `/(start|Start)/` or `/start|Start/` or like I do `/(S|s)tart/`

Comment: Fair enough, @Jotne. I had learnt it from your answer but did not want to copy into mine. Updated with a comment at the end. Thanks!

Comment: `/start/ || /Start/` should be written as `/[Ss]tart/`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one version:

```
awk '/End/{print a;f=a=0} f {a=a?a":"$0:$0} /(S|s)tart/{f=1}' file
a:b:c
a:b:c
x:y:z
```

I guess there is a typo in the first `start`, if so use:

```
awk '/End/{print a;f=a=0} f {a=a?a":"$0:$0} /Start/{f=1}' file
```

`/End/{print a;f=a=0}` If line contains `End` print `a`, and set `f` and `a` to `0`
`f {a=a?a":"$0:$0}` If `f` is true, set `a` to `$0` for first run and then `:$0` on the next run
`/Start/{f=1}` If line has `Start` set `f` to `1` (true)

Comment: The example which i gave in the question has only a,b,c or x,y,z but my actual file has Space in between. your solution also worked.. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

If there are always 3 lines between start and end:

```
grep -iv 'start\|end' file | paste -d: - - -
```

Comment: No i have uneven number of lines. I wil note down your answer too. It will be helpful for me

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n '/Start/,/End/ {
   /Start/ !{
      /End/ !H
      }
   /End/ {
      s/.*//
      x
      s/\n/:/g
      s/://
      p
      }
   }
/Start/,/End/ !p' YourFile
```

If **`start`** and `Start` should work replace `Start` by `[sS]tart` (and `End` by `[eE]nd`) in the code

**Explaination**

Start sed without printing the ouptut unless specific request

```
/Start/,/End/ {
```

For any block of line starting with `Start` and ending with `End` (on separate line)

```
/Start/ !{
          /End/ !H
          }
```

if line doesn not contain (the `!` ) `Start` than `End`, Add (append) the line to the holding buffer (kind of storage)

```
/End/ {
   s/.*//
   x
   s/\n/:/g
   s/://
   p
   }
```

when reach the line that contain `End`

1. Delete current line (the one with `End`)
2. exchange ( `x` )the Hold Buffer (with all line of the bloc stored) and Working Buffer (the one that can be manipulate and normaly have the current line)
3. Change all new line with `:` (the buffer contain all the line separate by new line after exchange)
4. remove first `:` (due to first Append that insert a new line)
5. print the content

   /Start/,/End/ !p

for all the line not ( `!` ) between the block between `Start` and `End`, print it

Comment: I add in answer for better understanding for new reader of the post

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative approach with GNU awk:

```
$ gawk -v RS='\0' '{ gsub(/\n/,":"); gsub(/:End:Start:/,"\n"); gsub(/^start:|:End:$/,"") }1' file     
a:b:c
a:b:c
x:y:z
```

Other awk solutions posted here are fine too.